# How to manage back end process with Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a web page that the user pushes a button and initiates an action in a proprietery app (which resides in Tomcat).

That action is a long running process and the only way I have to see what's going on is to log onto the server and look at a log file.

I wrote a quick Java function that reads the log file and gives feedback on what's happening.  (Essentially it just tails the file and parses out the things I need)

I'd like to be able to add a jsp that I can view the output without logging into the server.

===

From a design standpoint, I understand that the JSP should return quickly with a result and not just keep on processing.

So my idea is to create a simple web page that queries the jsp for an update and writes the latest info to the screen.  Wait 30 seconds, poll the server again, and append the latest update.

What I'm struggling to grasp is how to get the JSP to communicate with the back end process, and how that back end process should be spawned / killed.

This is a very occasional thing (once every two weeks, start to completion takes an hour or two), so I don't want a daemon running all the time.  I want to be able to turn it on temporarily and turn it off.

If I spawn a process from within a simple servlet, how do I end that process when I'm done?
And how do I communicate with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `java.lan.Runnable` witch reads the file content an saves it into a buffer. The Runnable reads the file content withing a `while` loop for witch the break condition can be set from outside, Thread that is executing your Runnable will terminate whe the `run` method of your Runnable terminates.

In your JSP you can create a `java.lang.Thread` and pass an instance of your Runnable to it. Save th instace of the runable in the `ServletContext` so you can access it across the requests. If you want to terminate the polling than just set the break condition of your Runnable from the JSP, the rum method will terminate and thus the thread too.

You can use javascript `setInterval()` function and `XMLHttpRequest` refresh the page.

here is a sample basic implemntation (I hope this will meet your requirements):

Polling Runnable

```
package com.web;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FilePollingThread implements Runnable {

    private String filepath = null;
    private boolean polling = false;
    private StringBuffer dataWritenAfterLastPoll = null;
    private String error = null;

    public FilePollingThread(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filepath)));
            dataWritenAfterLastPoll = new StringBuffer();
            polling = true;

            String line = null;

            while(polling) {
                try {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    while(line == null) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            error = e.toString();
                        }
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                    dataWritenAfterLastPoll.append(markUp(line));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = e.toString();
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = e.toString();
        } finally {
            if(br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = e.toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String markUp(String line) {
        String markup = "";
        if(line != null) {
            markup = "<div style=\"height: 6px\"><span style=\"line-height: 1.1;\">" + line + "</span></div>\n";
        }
        return markup;
    }

    public synchronized void stopPolling() {
        polling = false;
    }

    public synchronized String poll() {
        String tmp = markUp(error == null ? "Not ready" : error);
        if(dataWritenAfterLastPoll != null) {
            tmp = dataWritenAfterLastPoll.toString();
            dataWritenAfterLastPoll = new StringBuffer();
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

And a JSP witch initiats the polling an keep retrieving data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.web.FilePollingThread" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Poll file</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/default.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = 1;
    var ih;
    var polling = false;
    var filepath = null;
    function startPolling(interval) {
        ih = setInterval(function () {
            try {
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                        if(xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                            var w = getElementById('ajax_content');
                            w.innerHTML = w.innerHTML + xmlHttp.responseText;
                            getElementById('page_refresh').innerHTML = c++;
                            polling = true;
                            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                        } else {
                            polling = false;
                            throw 'HTTP ' + xmlHttp.status;
                        }
                    }
                };
                xmlHttp.open('GET', 'pollfile.jsp?filepath=' + filepath + '&c=' + c, true);
                xmlHttp.send();
            } catch(e) {
                alert('Error at startPolling: ' + e);
                clearInterval(ih);
            }
        }, interval);
    }

    function startStopPolling() {
        var orgPolling = polling;
        try {
            if(polling) {
                polling = false;
                clearInterval(ih);
                doPolling();
            } else {
                polling = true;
                doPolling();
                startPolling(1000);
            }
            flipStartStopButtonsLabel();
        } catch(e) {
            polling = orgPolling;
            flipStartStopButtonsLabel();
            alert('Error at startStopPolling: ' + e);
        }
    }

    function flipStartStopButtonsLabel() {
        var label;
        if(polling) {
            c = 1;
            label = 'Stop polling';
            getElementById('page_refresh').innerHTML = '0';
        } else {
            label = 'Sart polling';
            getElementById('page_refresh').innerHTML = 'stoped';
        }
        var buttons = document.getElementsByName('start_stop_polling');
        if(buttons) {
            for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                buttons[i].value = label;
            }
        }
    } 

    function doPolling() {
        var url = 'pollfile.jsp?polling=';
        if(polling) {
            filepath = getElementById('filepath');
            if(filepath && filepath.value && filepath.value.length > 0) {
                url += 'true&filepath=' + encodeURIComponent(filepath.value);
            } else {
                throw 'No filepath specified.';
            }
        } else {
            url += 'false';
        }
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                if(xmlHttp.status != 200) {
                    throw 'HTTP ' + xmlHttp.status;
                }
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open('POST', url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }

    function clearWindow() {
        var w = getElementById('ajax_content');
        if(w) {
            w.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }

    function getElementById(id) {
        try {
            if(id) {
                elm = document.getElementById(id);
                return elm;
            } 
        } catch(e) {
            alert('Error at getElementById: ' + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>


<%
    String polling = request.getParameter("polling");

    if("true".equals(polling)) {
        String filepath = request.getParameter("filepath");
        if(filepath != null && filepath.length() > 0) {
            FilePollingThread pollingThread = new FilePollingThread(filepath);
            new Thread(pollingThread, "polling thread for file '" + filepath + "'").start();
            request.getServletContext().setAttribute("pollingThread", pollingThread);
        }
    } else if("false".equals(polling)) {
        FilePollingThread pollingThread = (FilePollingThread) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("pollingThread");
        if(pollingThread != null) {
            pollingThread.stopPolling();
        }
    } else {
        FilePollingThread pollingThread = (FilePollingThread) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("pollingThread");
        if(pollingThread != null) {
            response.getWriter().println(pollingThread.poll());
            response.getWriter().close();
            return;
        }
    }
%>
<div class="label">
        <span>Page polling:</span>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <span id="page_refresh">0</span>
    </div>
<div class="clear_both">&nbsp;</div>
<form id="input_form" action="pollfile.jsp" method="get">
    <div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <label>Filepath:
                <input style="height: 24px;" id="filepath" type="text" size="120" value=""/>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"/>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <input style="height: 24px;" name="start_stop_polling" id="start_stop_polling_button" type="button" onclick="startStopPolling(); return false;" value="Start polling"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <input style="height: 24px;" name="clear_window" id="clear_window_button" type="button" onclick="clearWindow(); return false;" value="Clear"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="ajax_content">
</div>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input style="height: 24px;" name="start_stop_polling" id="start_stop_polling_button" type="button" onclick="startStopPolling(); return false;" value="Start polling"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input style="height: 24px;" name="clear_window" id="clear_window_button" type="button" onclick="clearWindow(); return false;" value="Clear"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

there is a bug in `FilePollingThread`: if no data is available in the file the thread might get stuck in inner while loop. it should be

```
while(line == null && polling)
```

also the JSP will not work on IE (testet on IE9). It seems that the data writen to the response in the line

```
response.getWriter().println(pollingThread.poll());
```

contains the HTML of the hole page. If added to the target div IE seems not able to render it.

I made another version using a simple static HTML file an a servlet as it offers more controle on what is writen to response.

If you are interested in the code let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using something like [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) to control your background process.

For control, your front-end code can send messages start/stop/inspect the process.
For monitoring, your process can publish to a JMS topic for your front end code to read.

Comment: interesting.  Is that kind of like RabbitMQ where I would have a message processor sitting in between the two?  So the file Tail utility would pass it's output to the message queue and whenever called the JSP would read the message queue?

Comment: Yes, RabbitMQ is one of several JMS providers. How you use JMS for your scenario is up to you, and your description is one of many that could work.